# I have two Linux distros dual-booted. I want to install Ubuntu and overwrite/delete Zorin OS

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, elementary

I have Zorin OS and Elementary OS installed on my laptop. I'd like to install Ubuntu  16.04 and replace Zorin OS. My question is, in the Ubuntu installation program, when it says "You have Zorin OS and Elementary OS installed on your computer", will it give me an option to write Ubuntu over *just one of them* (in this case Zorin OS) and leave eOS alone?

Hope I made sense...
Thanks.

Comment: No, I don't think so. It is also easy to try and see for yourself.

Comment: Why don't you just choose "Something else" / go manual and tell the installer to use the partition you want overwritten? You just need to make sure you select to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are speaking of a laptop, I think that both of the distributions are installed on the same HDD or SSD. In this case, you have to be very careful not to delete the whole disk. But you will be asked, if the disk should be deleted and overwritten (caution: NO!) or which partition should be overwritten, so that you can choose the partition with Zorin on it. Anyway, don’t forget to backup your home directory completely (preferably onto an external hard disk drive or flash drive).

Comment: Ok, I will try this and give an update on whether it worked.

Comment: Great! I’m glad I could help.